# How to fix 'Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code' error when building KMM iOS?

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when building KMM iOS

When I created the KMM project, I selected and created the iOS framework distribution as Regular framework and then built the project. At this time, Android works normally, but a problem occurred when building on iOS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEhyN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IackO.png)

Does anyone have the same problem as me?
If yes, how can it be solved?

Comment: open report navigator in xcode and look for build output - there should be logs of running the script with the actual error

Comment: The error that occurs during build is as follows.

"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"